# Can a variable be used as the array index in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

I have an array of objects that I am trying to add new objects to the first available 'null' location in the array. However, I am running into a runtime error whenever I attempt to add an object to the array. The error is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -211

    at Pokedex.addPokemon(Pokedex.java:37)
    at Project4.main(Project4.java:36)
```

The questionable code in the Pokedex class is:

```
public void addPokemon(Pokemon pkm){
    int blankSpace = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < billsPC.length; i++){
        if(billsPC[i] == pkm)
            System.out.println("Your Pokedex is already storing that Pokemon!");
        else{
            for(int j = 0; j < billsPC.length; j++){
                if(billsPC[j] == null)
                    blankSpace++;
            }
            if(blankSpace == 0)
                System.out.println("Your Pokedex is already holding the max amount!");
        }
    }
    int dexLoc;
    if (blankSpace == billsPC.length)
        dexLoc = 0;
    else
        dexLoc = billsPC.length - blankSpace - 1;
    //Line 37 is below
    billsPC[dexLoc] = pkm;
}
```

The questionable code from the Project4 class (line 36) is:

```
kantoDex.addPokemon(pkm);
```

where pkm is a set Pokemon object and kantoDex is a set Pokedex object.

Comment: Your bug is that `dexLoc` is -211, **as stated in the error message**. This is because your code calculating `blankSpace` is nested inside two loops, not one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can, indeed you are using it before (`billsPC[i]`).

The problem in your code, as the exception suggests, is that you are trying to access an array location out of bounds, in this case with index `-211`.

Comment: It is unlikely that this was caused by an overflow. It is more likely that `blankSpace` is higher than expected (see the comment under the question) and `billsPC.length - blankSpace - 1` resulted in the negative value.

Comment: @Tom you are right blankSpace is being substracted. I will edit my response

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is the nested loops. They cause `blankSpace` to increment too many times. As such `billsPC.length - blankSpace - 1` becomes a number much lesser than `0`.

The answer to your question is yes, variables can be used as the array index in Java.

I suspect this method might perform what you want:

```
public boolean addPokemon(Pokemon pkm) {
    for (int i = 0; i < billsPC.length; i++) {
        if (billsPC[i] == pkm) {
            System.out.println("Your Pokedex is already storing that Pokemon!");
            return false;
        }
        if (billsPC[i] == null) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < billsPC.length; j++) {
                if (billsPC[j] == pkm) {
                    System.out.println("Your Pokedex is already storing that Pokemon!");
                    return false;
                }
            }
            billsPC[i] = pkm;
            return true;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Your Pokedex is already holding the max amount!");
    return false;
}
```

The method will add `pkm` to the first `null`element of `billsPC` should such an element exist. If `billsPC` already contains `pkm` or no `null` element, it will print a message. Finally, it will return `true` if and only if `pkm` was successfully added to `billsPC`, else `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Can a variable be used as the array index in Java? yes but it should be in the bounds of array. `billsPC[-1] = pkm;//wrong`